# Share model like PayPal

Tags: java, android

If you know the story of Paypal, you know at the beginning, when you share the app you win 10$. I want make the same thing for my app, but you will not win money you will have a reduction for the premium version. I know how to share the app on social networks like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, URL_TO_SHARE);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Test"));
```

But how to verify if user really share the app for have the reduction ?

Answer (score 0):

you can add bool condition

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, URL_TO_SHARE);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Test"));
boolean isShared = true;
```

you can use isShared condition for premium privilege.
But you must save isShared variable, you can use [Sharedpreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) for saving variable to users phone storage.

Comment: What if the user aborts the sharing intent? What happens to `isShared`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out if the user actually shared the content and didn't just click the share button, you can do what is described in [this medium article](https://medium.com/code-with-lisa/get-results-from-android-chooser-9cfc5445a871).

Summary of that article:

The `ACTION_SEND` Intent will send a broadcast message if the user interacts with the share modal.
You can listen for that broadcast message.

1. Write a BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        // do something here
    }
}
```

And add the receiver to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="MyReceiver" android:exported="false"/>
```

2. Create an Intent with your receiver class as an argument:

```
Intent receiver = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);
```

3. Now create a PendingIntent which will notify the BroadcastReceiver:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

4. Create your share modal:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, URL_TO_SHARE);
```

5. Launch your intent:

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Test", pendingIntent.getIntentSender()));
```

6. Now you can get the selected app package in your onReceive Method:

```
String selectedAppPackage = String.valueOf(intent.getExtras().get(EXTRA_CHOSEN_COMPONENT))
```